# c# unity pause a for loop untill bool returns true

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i have a for loop that loops through a class array instantiating a new player class and passing in a string(name).

```
public void createPlayers( int pInput)
{
    //holds name
    string temporaryString="defualt";
    players = new Player[pInput];
   

    for (int i = 0; i < pInput; ++i)
    {
       
        //PlayerTypesNameFunction()// this gets and returns a string to Temporary String
        //wait till function returns with true meaning player(i) has entered name

        players[i] = new Player(100,temporaryString);
        Debug.Log(players[i].m_sName);
    } 
        
    CurrentState = GameState.m_eQueueWeather;
    CallGameCurrentState();


}
```

I want it to call a function which gets the player to type a name and only continue for loop when that function finishes.
changes a bool to true(bool gotInfo), the loop then continues to take the string which is returned and stored in `temporaryString` (string instatiated above) and assigns it to the new player in this line `players[i] = new Player(100,temporaryString);`.

Am I heading in the right direction or should I approach this problem differently?
Thank you in advance

Comment: i just want to know how to pause the for loop with a bool , then pick up where it was in the loop when bool is true

Comment: I would suggest you look into how to do this in an event driven way. Have one function to show your UI for the user to type their name into and then have a callback that receives the data when the user indicates they are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest the infinite loop here. I would go for the `yield return` subrutine method that's explained [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/586609/waiting-for-input-via-coroutine.html)

Create the subrutine

```
 IEnumerator WaitForKeyDown(KeyCode keyCode)
 {
     while (!Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode))
         yield return null;
 }
```

Wait wherever you want

```
 yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForKeyDown(KeyCode.Return));
```

This will resume when the user presses enter. You can then check the input value and re-ask.

Comment: yield return new WaitUntil(()=>Input.GetKeyDown(keycode); for a short version.